# Password is not encrypted in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I create a new user, his password remains unencrypted in the database.

Here is my models.py file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.db import models

from .managers import UserManager


class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True, primary_key=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.phone

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.phone
```

serializers.py:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    phone = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

views.py:

```
class UserProfileViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

managers.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, phone, password, **extra_fields):
        if not phone or not password:
            raise ValueError('Err!')
        user = self.model(phone=phone, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, phone, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(phone, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, phone, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
        return self._create_user(phone, password, **extra_fields)
```

in settings.py i have wrote that:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.UserProfile'
```

Using print, I found out that no UserManager methods are used when creating a user. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are answering your own question: you are not using the manager methods to create the user, you are just saving the data. Implement `UserProfileSerializer.save` and call `User.objects.create_user` there instead of using `ModelSerializer.save` (it doesn’t know that your model is a user model).

Comment: Thank you, i have no idea how I could not see it.

Comment: @thejesh-pr first of all rename `post` method in view to `create`. Next step: add `create` method inside of serializer, That method must invoke `save` method of model and returns user object. BTW I am here and I can answer to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

In the serializers.py write the create method:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    phone = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False) 
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, write_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = '__all__'
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

def create(self, validated_data):
    return UserProfile.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

Reference:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances

Comment: Welcome! Please note that the [policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/) is that [questions and answers need to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange).